# How to fix a mysql dump file if it has blob field but dump without use --hex-blob parameter?

Tags: mysql, blob, dump

I use MySQL 5.5 and dump a database. But I forget that this database has some blob filed!

I use MySQL dump command to dump the database, without use the hex-blob  parameter! So, after i get the file, I can't import to my MySQL, it is said that unknown command. But i have to import the data to my another MySQL server. How can i repair this database?

```
myqldump -u root -p -h localhost abc>c:\abc.sql
```

as you see, I forget use the --hex-blob parameter!

Answer (score 0):

If *nix, have you tried to load `mysql abc

But, since this is Windows, you have probably been screwed by NL turning into CRLF.